# Отслеживание комментариев и мониторинг информации

Tags: вконтакте

Здравствуйте! Имеются ли у кого на примете бесплатные инструменты для отслеживания новых комментариев, в частности — в сообществах ВКонтакта?

P.S. Если говорить о платных сервисах, таких как [chotam.ru](https://chotam.ru) или [starcomment.ru](https://starcomment.ru) — правильно ли понимаю, что ими ежеминутно скачивается и парсится каждый пост выбранного пользователем сообщества?

Comment: Вы свои сообщества хотите мониторить или чужие?

Comment: В данный момент интересуют чужие. Предполагается мониторить все новые комментарии в определенном сообществе.